# Electron App Getting Exception While requiring SQLITE3

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

**package.json**

```
"name": "billingapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w billingapp"
},
"author": "S Kundu",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"electron": "^1.7.11",
"sqlite3": "^3.1.13"
}
"devDependencies": {
"electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3"
}
```

**index.js**

```
const electron  = require('electron');
const path      = require('path');
const url       = require('url');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(path.join(__dirname, 'sample.db'));

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain} = electron;

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', function(){


// Create the login window
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  resizable: true,
  fullscreen: false
});

// Load html in window
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'login.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
}));
});
```

**login.html**

```
<h1>Welcome to billing system</h1>
```

These are the code files.

Steps to install NPM Packages

```
npm install electron
npm install sqlite3
```

Its working perfect when I remove bellow code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(path.join(__dirname, 'sample.db'));
```

But  with this code , while running

```
npm start
```

**is getting bellow error:**

App threw an error during load

> Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\BillingSystem\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.7-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
>       at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\BillingSystem\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\BillingSystem\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\BillingSystem\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:190:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)

when I run npm run rebuild , I get bellow error

× Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.7.11" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.7-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v3.1.13/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v1.7-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1

Error: Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.7.11" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.7-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v3.1.13/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v1.7-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:277:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:239:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:198:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:129:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:129:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:251:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:239:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\sintu\Desktop\billingApp\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:186:22)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 4294967295
npm ERR! billingapp@1.0.0 rebuild: `electron-rebuild -f -w billingapp`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the billingapp@1.0.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sintu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-01-30T15_36_46_678Z-debug.log

Comment: You did run `npm install` after adding sqlite as a dependency, right?

Comment: Yes, I have done

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have many problems with your scripts, but you also encountered a rare issue with sqlite.

0) You can find my Github source [here](https://github.com/Aminelahlou/stackoverissue.git) that is working until this error :

```
Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

but that is another problem :D

1) Your package.json is not well formated (there is no start script for example)

New package.json

```
{ // there was no begining bracket
  "name": "billingapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w billingapp",
    "start": "node index.js" // new start script
  },
  "author": "S Kundu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.11",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.0" // I used this version
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

2) When I installed sqlite I encountered this issue https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/758

It seems sqlite3 is not working with the last version of nodejs, so you need to install node@8.9.3 you can use nvm for that:

see comment on sqlite3 issue

> treedbox commented on 20 Dec 2017